# when the inverse of a triple diagonal matrix is triple diagonal?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is there any special case that the inverse of a symmetric triple diagonal matrix A is triple diagonal? Under which assumptions?

Comment: The word most commonly used for matrices whose nonzero entries are on or one place above or below the diagonal is *tridiagonal*.  The inverse of a tridiagonal matrix is typically a full (dense) matrix, though special cases can be contrived.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for your comment. As you mentioned, the inverse is generally a full dense matrix. I want to know is there any theoretical case that the inverse is still triple diagonal?

Comment: It is sufficient that there is exactly one non-zero off diagonal entry, and this may also be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be of interest (the Question lacks context), but a block diagonal matrix consisting of $2\times 2$ blocks would have an inverse of the same form, provided each of those blocks are invertible.  Those would be [tridiagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) with tridiagonal inverses.

Moreover we can freely mix invertible blocks of size $1$ or $2$ to form a block diagonal matrix which is thus tridiagonal and has a tridiagonal inverse (with the same block diagonal structure).

The inverses of general tridiagonal matrices are a class of matrices called *semiseparable* (of rank $1$).  There is a good bit of literature on the subject; for a survey see "A note on the representation and definition of semiseparable matrices" by Vanderbril, van Barel, and Mastronardi ([2003](https://www.academia.edu/528014/A_note_on_the_representation_and_definition_of_semiseparable_matrices)).  These are another kind of *rank-structured matrix* which can be compactly represented (similar to tridiagonal matrices).